# Where does Eclipse on a PC store the database?

Tags: android, database, eclipse, ddms

I have Eclipse installed on a Windows 7 PC and I'm writing my app there, using an emulator.

In DDMS within Eclipse, I can see the database my app has created BUT it is shown in a UNIX directory structure, as I might find it on an Android device, not in the context of a Windows directory structure.

The file must exist physically on my C: drive or a network drive somewhere but I've done a search with windows explorer and it cannot find the DB. I can find all my project files ok.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you want your db file from your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DB, like any other files the app creates are stored in the emulator. Most likely there is only an image of the whole emulator file system stored on the host. you will not find the individual files.

To get access to them, they can be exported via adb or via the Eclipse DDMS user interface. This is just like working with a real device.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to view the data in your .db file:

**1.** In DDMS, select the .db file in the File Explorer and click on Pull File. This way you can save the file somewhere on your PC like your desktop for instance.

**2.** One way to see the data in the file is to use the **SQLite Manager** add-on for Firefox.

Comment: @Nelmo: While the accepted answer is indeed correct, my answer also works, and serves as an alternative ... I request you to please upvote it as it will be useful to others ... thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps.

Eclipse -> Window -> Show View -> others -> File Explorer -> data -> data -> your project package -> databases.

You can export your database in this location.